# Why do people trust PlayFramework2 dependency management?

Tags: java, web-service

If you worked in a big company that was very security conscious, would you build a product based on [PlayFramework2](http://www.playframework.com/) underneath?  Since it does automatic dependency resolution at load time, aren't you placing a lot of trust in some possibly untrustworthy source of updated libraries?

Why would you trust it?  How do you know that the libraries it's downloading from the wild are safe?  Wouldn't it be possible for a hacker to compromise the source of the libraries, injecting some unknown code into it?

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you're asking, because you answer your own question. Any external library could potentially be unsafe. The real question is (as it always is): what do you need to protect against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Misconceptions**

Play Framework 2 doesn't have its own dependency management or repositories, it uses SBT which in turn uses the existing [Maven Central repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven/), which is where pretty much all Java packages live.

Regarding the downloading on load, this does not happen. No libraries are downloaded when you run an application built with SBT. Libraries are downloaded when you *build the project with SBT*. Usually only once, after which SBT saves libraries to ( default for Maven ) `~/.m2/repositories`.

**Trusting Maven Central**

Maven Central has some requirements on security:

> To improve the quality of the Central Maven repository, we require you to provide PGP signatures for all your artifacts (all files except checksums), and distribute your public key to a key server like http://pgp.mit.edu.

Meaning you can verify yourself whether something is uploaded by an entity you trust.

> Only releases can be uploaded to the central repository, that means files that won't change and that only depend on other files already released and available in the repository.

This basically means that if a user of Maven Central would get "hacked", noone can replace any libraries that user released. They would only be able to release newer *versions*, which  unless you're using dependency version wildcards, your software will remain safe.

**Custom Repositories**

There's a bunch of alternative repositories ( i.e. JBoss' ), but most importantly you can also use a tool like [Sonatype's Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) to be your own Maven Repository. If you really want to be sure nothing malicious is going on you can set up a company Nexus and upload only verified trusted libraries to it.

**Bottom line**

It's pretty much like any package manager or [software repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository), and completely up to you whether you trust the people behind it. In my opninion it's a lot safer than downloading libraries from the internet yourself.

Comment: Very helpful.  Of course anyone can create a PGP key and sign anything they want. How well do the tools support verifying the real identity of the signer of an artifact or evaluating their reputation? If the signer changes from one version to the next, is the developer warned by SBT?